# LibGdx PolygonSpriteBatch not drawing all polygons

Tags: java, libgdx

I am trying to render a simple 2D landscape profile using PolygonSpriteBatch in libGdx to draw filled polygons on screen.  I am no sure why, but the code only appears to be rendering every other polygon resulting in a striped pattern on screen (see screen shot below - the background is red, the landscape is green).

[image: Game screenshot]

The code that I am using to draw the landscape is shown below.  This iterates through a set of adjacent points in World co-ordinates (retrieved using landarray.getOnScreen()), calculates the screen co-ordinates, creates a PolygonRegion for each segment and draws them.  The texture that I am using is just a 100x100 pixel solid white square.  I am not using any cameras or views, just converting World co-ordinates to screen co-ordinates on the fly and drawing directly to the graphics screen.

Note that I am re-writing this game from a working version that uses Slick2D (hence not using cameras at this stage) and the code below is more or less unchanged (other than to flip the y axis height calculations) from the working version, which draws a continuous landscape.

```
public void drawPoly() {
    System.out.println("Mountains - drawShape()");
    // Calculate screen bottom-edge Y taking into account values = bHEIGHT
    int scrBtmY = scrTopY - Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
    if (FastMath.abs(scrBtmY) == bHEIGHT) {         // Wrap-around bug at y == bHEIGHT
        scrBtmY = 0;
    }

    // Draw the land masses on-screen that are in the results list
    polyBatch.begin();
    polyBatch.setColor(landColour);
    ArrayList<Landmass> masses = landarray.getOnScreen(scrLeftX, scrTopY, scrBtmY);
    for (Landmass lm : masses) {
        /* Calculate the on-screen start and end x and y values taking into account
           wrapping in 'buffer space'
           Wrap around - low negative numbers (> -25) are 'just off screen' start or
           end points, large ones are wrap-around points
         */
        int sx = (int) lm.start.x - scrLeftX;
        if (sx < -Settings.Physics.LANDSITEWIDTH) {
            sx = sx + bWIDTH;
        }

        int sy = (int) lm.start.y - scrBtmY;

        int ex = (int) lm.end.x - scrLeftX;
        if (ex < -Settings.Physics.LANDSITEWIDTH) {     // Wrap around
            ex = ex + bWIDTH;          
        }

        int ey = (int) lm.end.y - scrBtmY;
        ex = ex - 1;        // In case over-lapping regions is causing stripes

        System.out.format("start (%d, %d)\t end (%d, %d)%n", sx, sy, ex, ey);

        // Construct and draw the polygon
        float[] vertices = new float[8];
        vertices[0] = sx;
        vertices[1] = 0;
        vertices[2] = ex;
        vertices[3] = 0;
        vertices[4] = ex;
        vertices[5] = ey;
        vertices[6] = sx;
        vertices[7] = sy;
        short[] triangles = new short[] {0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3};
        PolygonRegion polyReg = new PolygonRegion(new TextureRegion(textureSolid), vertices, triangles);
        polyBatch.draw(polyReg, sx, 0);
    }
    polyBatch.end();
}
```

I have included a debug line to print out the on-screen co-ordinates of the individual polygons (landmass segments) and the output from one drawPoly() iteration is shown below.  This shows the start (x, y) and end (x, y) co-ordinates for each segment that should be drawn on screen.  From the output, the drawn polygons appear to be adjacent to each other and therefore should not have gaps between them.

```
Mountains - drawShape()
start (53, 265)  end (77, 358)
start (78, 358)  end (102, 376)
start (103, 376)     end (127, 406)
start (128, 406)     end (152, 371)
start (153, 371)     end (177, 429)
start (178, 429)     end (202, 447)
start (203, 447)     end (227, 433)
start (228, 433)     end (252, 415)
start (253, 415)     end (277, 478)
start (278, 478)     end (302, 490)
start (303, 490)     end (327, 524)
start (328, 524)     end (352, 519)
start (353, 519)     end (377, 551)
start (378, 551)     end (402, 556)
start (403, 556)     end (427, 543)
start (428, 543)     end (452, 470)
start (453, 470)     end (477, 505)
start (478, 505)     end (502, 482)
start (503, 482)     end (527, 513)
start (528, 513)     end (552, 476)
start (553, 476)     end (577, 479)
start (578, 479)     end (602, 460)
start (603, 460)     end (627, 475)
start (628, 475)     end (652, 426)
start (653, 426)     end (677, 453)
start (-22, 449)     end (2, 406)
start (3, 406)   end (27, 357)
start (28, 357)  end (52, 265)
```

I have searched through a range of posts on this site, which have helped me to get the code as it is above, but not seen any post with this specific problem.

Note I am running this as the desktop version only and have enabled Java 8 for this purpose.  Tested using both libGdx 1.5.6 and 1.6.0 with the same result.

I have produced a standalone version of the code to replicate the problem in case anyone wants to try this at home. This uses libGdx 1.6.0 and (I assume) Java 6 and shows the problem as described above (on my PC at least). The files can be found here: [java source](https://www.dropbox.com/s/j0u6afq3dt50rnp/MyGdxGame.java?dl=0), [png image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xdplr4oyuruij0e/land.png?dl=0) and [whole project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bcrfrdqugbuujw4/TestPolgyonSpriteBatch.zip?dl=0) in a zip file.

Does anyone have any idea why I am getting the striped effect on screen?

Comment: I have developed a workaround using a ShapeRenderer with ShapeType.Filled and drawing two triangles for each segment using the vertices that I calculate.  However, this does not answer the question above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PolygonRegion vertex coordinates are supposed to be offsets relative to the polygon's TextureRegion origin and are not supposed to be absolute screen coordinates, which is what I *think* you're doing from your output (since you're creating the vertex with the unmodified coordinates).

I suggest you modify your vertex coordinates to become lengths.

I had this exact same problem, and this was the only result on Google. I thought I'd share my solution.

Edit:

Here's my own solution for the sake of clarity.

```
vertices = new float[] { 0, 0,
                        lTX-lBX, lTY-lBY,
                        rTX-lBX, rTY-lBY,
                        rBX-lBX, rBY-lBY};
```

My terrible naming scheme aside, the above defines a quadrilateral polygon in terms of UV coordinates. lBX (left base x) and lBY (left base y) are the starting position of of my polygon in screen coordinates. They lie directly on the TextureRegion's origin and so are offset by 0,0. lTX (left top x) and lTY (left top y) is the next position. Again, I find the distance from the origin by subtracting the two from lBX and lBY. And so on and so forth for the rest of my coordinates.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  Yes, I am using screen co-ordinates as my vertices.  I've taken this from the libgdx PolygonRegion javadoc: "_vertices - contains 2D polygon coordinates in pixels relative to source region_".  Can you clarify your understanding of what this means by "_source region_".  I have changed my test app so that the 1st co-ordinate pair of each PolygonRegion is the origin in screen co-ordinates (taking this as the "source") and the remaining 3 pairs are distances from this, but it still gives the wrong result.  I assume I am misunderstanding what "_source region_" means in this context.

Comment: A libgdx PolygonRegion necessarily has an associated TextureRegion. To quote the documentation: "Defines a polygon shape on top of a texture region to avoid drawing transparent pixels." This is your source region. The origin is the bottom left (or top right I'm not entirely sure which) corner of your TextureRegion. 
(edit: accidentally pressed enter)
If your TextureRegion is the entirety of the texture and is not a sprite sheet(for instance), then your origin should be defined at (0,0).

Comment: I've edited my answer above if you're interested in seeing my implementation.

Comment: Perfect.  Thank you, thank you, thank you.  :)  That works a treat.  I've just noticed that when I draw the region, the PolygonSpriteBatch.draw() method takes x and y parameters so the TextureRegion doesn't need any co-ordinates setting.  Everything is set relative to (0, 0) in the PolygonRegion and then you tell the PolygonSpriteBatch where to draw it on screen as follows:
`PolygonSpriteBatch.draw(PolygonRegion, int x, int y);`
I'll upload my test application for future reference so others can see how this works.

Answer (score 0):

As promised, here is my working test program for using a PolygonSpriteBatch:

```
/* PolygonSpriteBatch test using libgdx 
    Author: Twelve1110
    Date: 6 June 2015
*/
package test;

import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.PolygonRegion;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.PolygonSpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureRegion;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class TestPolygonSpriteBatch extends ApplicationAdapter {

    PolygonSpriteBatch polyBatch;
    SpriteBatch batch;
    Texture img;                                
    ArrayList<Landmass> masses;
    TextureRegion texRegion;

    @Override
    public void create() {
        Gdx.graphics.setDisplayMode(600, 480, false);
        polyBatch = new PolygonSpriteBatch();
        masses = this.buildLandmass();
        img = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("land.png"));  // 100 by 100 pixel plain white jpg
        texRegion = new TextureRegion(img);                 // Create new texture region with base image
    }

    @Override
    public void render() {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        // Calculate screen left-edge X and bottom-edge Y (normally done in a game with moving screen)
        int scrBtmY = 0;
        int scrLeftX = 0;

        // Draw the landscape on-screen
        polyBatch.begin();
        polyBatch.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        for (Landmass lm : masses) {
            // Calculate start and end x and y values taking into account wrapping in 'buffer space'
            int sx = (int) lm.start.x - scrLeftX;
            int sy = (int) lm.start.y - scrBtmY;

            int ex = (int) lm.end.x - scrLeftX;
            int ey = (int) lm.end.y - scrBtmY;

            // Create polygon vertices
            float[] vertices = new float[8];                // Create polygon with bottom-left corner = (0, 0)
            vertices[0] = 0;                                // Bottom-left
            vertices[1] = 0;
            vertices[2] = (ex - sx) + 1;                    // Bottom-right; all points are lengths away from (0, 0); 
            vertices[3] = 0;
            vertices[4] = (ex - sx) + 1;                    // Top-right
            vertices[5] = ey;
            vertices[6] = 0;                                // Top-left
            vertices[7] = sy;

            // Define how to divide polygon into trianlges, create region and draw...
            short[] triangles = new short[]{0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3};  // Define points of polygons to be used in triangles (could be done in 'create' method
            PolygonRegion polyReg = new PolygonRegion(texRegion, vertices, triangles);
            polyBatch.draw(polyReg, sx, 0);                 // Pass screen co-ordinates here to draw PolygonRegion in correct place on screen
        }
        polyBatch.end();
    }

    public ArrayList<Landmass> buildLandmass() {
        ArrayList<Landmass> list = new ArrayList();
        int[] coordinates = new int[]{                      // Set of polygons to be drawn in screen co-ordinates
            -22, 449, 2, 406, 3, 406, 27, 357, 
            28, 357, 52, 265, 53, 265, 77, 358, 
            78, 358, 102, 376, 103, 376, 127, 406, 
            128, 406, 152, 371, 153, 371, 177, 429, 
            178, 429, 202, 447, 203, 447, 227, 433, 
            228, 433, 252, 415, 253, 415, 277, 478, 
            278, 478, 302, 490, 303, 490, 327, 524, 
            328, 524, 352, 519, 353, 519, 377, 551, 
            378, 551, 402, 556, 403, 556, 427, 543, 
            428, 543, 452, 470, 453, 470, 477, 505, 
            478, 505, 502, 482, 503, 482, 527, 513,
            528, 513, 552, 476, 553, 476, 577, 479, 
            578, 479, 602, 460, 603, 460, 627, 475, 
            628, 475, 652, 426, 653, 426, 677, 453};

        for (int i = 0; i < 28; i++) {                      // Create landmass array of polygons
            Landmass lm = new Landmass();
            int pt = i * 4;
            lm.start.x = coordinates[pt];
            lm.start.y = coordinates[pt + 1];
            lm.end.x = coordinates[pt + 2];
            lm.end.y = coordinates[pt + 3];
            list.add(lm);
        }
        return list;
    }

    public class Landmass {
        public Vector2 start;
        public Vector2 end;

        Landmass() {
            start = new Vector2();
            end = new Vector2();
        }       
    }

}
```